# Google Games scary permission for signin: "Create, edit, and delete your Google Play Games activity"

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I just migrated one of my apps from Google Plus signin to Google Signin and updated some achievements code, as I was using deprecated methods and Google Plus is disappearing.

To my surprise, the permissions dialog that shows up when a user signs in to Google Games has change in a scary way:

Before, it said the app could:

> - View your langiage preferences
> - View your age range
> - Share your Google+ profile information and view and manage your game activity
> - View your basic profile info

With the new version, it just says:

> - Create, edit, and delete your Google Play Games activity

Does anyone know where this is coming from?

In the process of migrating libraries (I also installed Firebase analytics), some new API keys were automatically created in my Google APIs dashboard, and an additional OAuth 2.0 client ID. There, under "OAuth consent screen" I can see many scopes my app is supposedly using that look unnecessary to me:

```
../auth/plus.circles.members.read   
../auth/plus.login  
../auth/plus.profile.agerange.read  
profile 
../auth/drive.appdata   
openid  
../auth/plus.login  
../auth/plus.profile.agerange.read  
../auth/plus.profile.language.read  
../auth/games   
../auth/games_lite  
../auth/plus.moments.write
```

Can I delete the ones that I don't think I need? Will this remove the scary warning?

One of the other apps I have not yet updated shows fewer scopes (still more than I need):

```
../auth/plus.circles.members.read   
profile 
openid  
../auth/plus.login  
../auth/plus.profile.agerange.read  
../auth/plus.profile.language.read  
../auth/games   
../auth/plus.moments.write
```

Thanks

Edit: From what I've found out so far, the auth screen depends on the way you create the client used to sign in, and I think I'm using a pretty standard way:

```
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build());
```

Edit 2: I went to my API console, restricted the uses and scopes of my app, resubmitted my OAuth screen for approval, GOT IT APPROVED... and the Android app keeps showing the scary auth screen.

I also contacted Google for help from the Play Dev Console. Received no reply.

I'm just following  Google's advice. As stated here,

```
// This way you won’t get a consent screen
GoogleSignInOptions signInOption = GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN;
```

https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist

Edit 3:
After I got my simplified OAuth screen approved. Firebase created new api keys on its own, so I'm guessing it doesn't like the changes I made manually. I am alos getting non-fatal crash reports from users rejecting the app permissions (error 12501) after trying to access the achievements screen. Google has not responded at all.

Comment: Any resolution?  A friend asked me something similar.

Comment: They ignored me for a long time. Just recently they closed the issue as per this: "Our technical team spent some time looking into this and they confirmed that the behavior you're reporting is working as intended. 

Please note that Google recently informed in our security blog post that Google will expand the notification to users whenever users are sharing any data from their Google Account."

Comment: Ah, I see.  In other words, "We're not going to change it, and we don't care about your problems."  Typical of Google.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem and got it fixed using

GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN

instead of `GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN`